# induction on negative exponent of operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory

I was reading through 'Linear algebra done right' by Sheldon Axler, and this came up:

"You should verify that if $T$ is an operator, then
$$T^mT^n = T^{m+n}$$ and $$(T^m)^n = T^{mn}$$
where $m$ and $n$ are allowed to be arbitrary integers if $T$ is invertible and nonnegative integers if $T$ is not invertible."

I know how to verify the second case by induction, however i have no idea how to proceed to prove the first. I tried something i call 'induction for negative numbers' showing $P(n)\implies P(n-1)$ (where $P(n):T^mT^n=T^{m+n}$) but i don't know if this is correct. Can someone give a full answer of what's supposed to be shown or at least explain it?

Comment: I believe that for negative number you need to use the definition $T^{n-1} = T^{n} \circ T^{-1}.$ Maybe try proving first $T^{n} = (T^{-1})^{-n}.$

Comment: Usually, induction proceeds as follows: define a set $H$ of integers $n \geq 1$ such that some proposition $P(n)$ is true. Then you show $1 \in H$ and $n \in H \implies n + 1 \in H.$ If you want to do for negatives, you can do similarly by defining $H$ the set of integers $n \geq 1$ such that $P(-n)$ is true.